# Create maven archetype with custom params using requiredProps and fileSets

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I need to create a new `maven archetype` where project files contains some custom params that I would like to provide for `mvn archetype:generate`. Only `-DgroupId`, `-DartifactId` and `version` works fine. But I cannot provide e.g. `-Dparam1=value1` .

I tried using `requiredProperties` and `fileSets`, but it doesn't work. **How can I achieve that ?**

*archetype.xml*

```
<archetype xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-1.0.0.xsd">
    <id>my-archetype</id>

    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="param1">
            <defaultValue>lol</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8" >
            <directory>src/main/</directory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

    <resources>
        <resource>src/main/someFile.txt</resource>
    </resources>

</archetype>
```

*src/main/someFile.txt*

```
I am just a txt file, but I need ${param1} value to be here !
```

I also need the pom.xml of my project (the one that is generated when `mvn archetype:generate`) to have custom properties replaced.

*pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${artifactId}-server</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>This name has to contains ${param1} !</name>

    // ... all the rest stuff
</project>
```

Comment: I have spent some time and managed to do this on my own. I created a simple app to demo this stuff on my GitHub https://github.com/ikos23/maven-archetype-sample . Maybe this will be usefull for somebody as well.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [archetype descriptor documentation](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html) the archetype descriptor needs to be named `archetype-metadata.xml`. The example shows `archetype.xml`.

Also note, the initial XML element is `archetype-descriptor`, not just `archetype`.

Files must also be in a well-defined location for the plugin to find them.

```
<yourArchetypeProject>
  src
    main
      resources
        archetype-resources
          <files and directories for project>
      META-INF
        maven
          archetype-metadata.xml
```

The Maven docs could definitely be clearer on this. I found [this tutorial](http://geekofficedog.blogspot.com/2013/08/creating-maven-archetypes-tutorial.html) helpful when I was learning.